# What is the correct size screw of a 8.3mm countersink bit

Tags: wood, wood-repair

The screws I have are 10g..does this countersink bit work or should I refund and what is the correct size countersink bit

Comment: Hi, welcome to Woodworking. Are you asking about a combined drill bit with countersink fitted like a collar? But in general there isn't just one size screw that a countersink is good for since a larger countersink can always be used to create a smaller countersink depression in the wood, by just not going as deep. In the old days it was common to have just one (quite large) countersink as a result, which would be used to prepare holes for all sizes of screw.

Comment: Use your countersink to make some practice holes of varying depths in a scrap piece of wood  and then see if the screw fits in one of them. If it does then you are golden. that is the depth you need to use for the screws you have.

Answer (score 2):

I did some research and for a 10g screw they suggest 1/8 - 9/64 or 3.6mm countersink bit.